# Excel - Checking Values of Cells Across Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet that provides monthly results for the last year. The layout is 7 columns per month, each column is the same information for each month (count and rate of various things).

I need to trigger a true/false based on both count and rate being above threshold values in any of the twelve months.

I can do this using either nested IFs or just a lot of IF statements, but was wondering if anyone has a better suggestion? I am open to formulas or VBA, whatever would be most robust.

Image of how each month is arranged
[image]

Comment: use IF Else formula. Thats clean and about right what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell from your spreadsheet what the layout is, but I tried to recreate it (See image below). I entered the function `=IF(OR(B2>0.04,C2>2),$A$2)` into cell A7 and dragged it across the spreadsheet. All the values you're looking for should be under the Month column. To prevent the function from changing its reference to the first column `Name`, I used absolute referencing, with dollar symbols `$A$2`. This way you don't have to keep changing it back to the specified column. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll end up using the IF(OR... or something similar